# SMTP server without using default port(587)

Tags: c#

```
SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient(MailServer);
System.Net.NetworkCredential SMTPUserInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(sender_mail_id(organisation mail id), pwd);
emailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
emailClient.Credentials = SMTPUserInfo;

emailClient.Port = 587;
emailClient.Send(msg);
```

Above code for sending mail is working. I would like to configure my own port (my outlook outgoing server port) ie instead of 587. How to do that? (My organisation outlook id is attached with yahoo id)

Comment: Silly question, why do you have `emailClient.Port = Convert.ToInt32("587");` instead of: `emailClient.Port = 587;` ?

Comment: .. also, why not just change `587` to whatever the port is?

Comment: when i change am getting following error "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

Comment: So you're asking how to configure your mail server? Go talk to your network manager - it sounds like the program isn't the problem.

Comment: where are you creating the message..? please show all the code that is relevant to your issue in question..

Comment: ok...thank you for your replay.

Comment: Raghu I posted an example for you to use / test change the values to fit your `use case`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that you can use to follow for example use it anyway you like to fit your example

```
    MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();
    mailMsg.To.Add("somEmailAddress@SomMailHost.com");
    // From
    MailAddress mailAddress = new MailAddress("spongebob@sandymail.com");
    mailMsg.From = mailAddress;

    // Subject and Body
    mailMsg.Subject = "subject";
    mailMsg.Body = "body";

    // Init SmtpClient and send on port 587
    SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient("mailserver", 587);
    System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
    emailClient.Credentials = credentials;
    emailClient.Send(mailMsg);
```